# kafka retention period has reached but still old segment exist

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running a kafka cluster in production environment  with default retention configuration which is log.retention.hours=168 and log.segment.bytes=1073741824. So after sever days I am seeing that one new segment has been created and logs are updating on the new segment. But still old segment exist.

Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood your log consists of segements which are basically files on disk. They are kept open and being written to until either you hit by default either 7 days of retention or 1Gb size. Then Kafka "rolls" which means it closes the file and opens a new one.

In the "worst case" this means you have a single file with 7 days worth of data and the newest message is zero days old. Kafka may only delete it after the newest message is out of retention, so after an additional seven days. The thing to look out for is a message like

```
[2022-03-16 13:33:10,749] INFO [Log partition=requests-0, dir=/kafka/data] Deleting segment LogSegment(baseOffset=1, size=132, lastModifie
dTime=1647437528000, largestRecordTimestamp=Some(1647437529695)) due to retention time 60000ms breach based on the largest record timestam
p in the segment (kafka.log.Log)
```

in your *broker* logs. This will be logged, when Kafka deletes a segment.

The strimzi blog https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/12/17/kafka-segment-retention/ does a really good job of explaining this in more detail if you are interested.

To change this behaviour, I have set `log.roll.ms` before. This forces Kafka to roll files faster and therefore they will breach retention earlier. This will, however, increase the number of filehandlers on your cluster which can affect e.g. restart and rebalance time.

Comment: thnx for your reply. But new log also become 5 days old. Actually on 21st Oct'22 new segment rolled out and on 21st Oct'22 , 7 days completed.  So I hope old segment should be deleted. Anything am I missing?

Comment: If the segment rolled on October 21st then the *newest* message in your *old* segment is probably from October 21st also. This would mean the whole segment is eligible for deletion on October 28th.

Comment: If the old segment was deleted right now, that would mean there is a message which Kafka for only 5 days. So it keeps the whole segment until everything in there is *at least* seven days old

Comment: actually kafka started on 14th oct and on 21st Oct new segment rolled on and 7 days passed as well. So in this case old segment should be deleted. Am I missing something? @maow

Comment: It deletes it 7 days after it rolls, 14 days in total. That is not before Friday.

Comment: Yes it deleted .